# Self validation of links from HTML-Helper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I prevent links automaticly from beeing displayed in the Template ctp files?

I will give you an example:

User(id = 1) is allowed to see teamcalendars/view/1
User(id = 2) is not allowed to see teamcalendars/view/1.

User1 is member of the team 1 and should see and follow the link. User2 is not member in any teams and neither should see the link to the calender nor follow it. But I would like to place the link in the teams/index file where both users can go to and see all teams, but with different options per team.

If User2 follows the link (or types it into the browser manually), the controller will return a redirect and a error message about missing privileges. User2 will anyhow never get there. But how do I prevent cake from displaying the link for User2 (its missleading)?

Is there a possibility to connect the link to the controller and action and the id of the object where it is leading to, so I don't neet to take care of building and passing variables for each view just to decide which links can be displayed?

Sorry for not providing any code, but I think anyone knows how to send an array from the Controller to the View and how to validate it with if(){echo $this->Html->link()}, which is what I am doing currently.

Thank you for any help or remarks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define your own HtmlHelper and override the link function, such that it checks the permissions on the link first and only outputs it if they are allowed access. Something like the following:

```
namespace App\View\Helper;
use \Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper;
// Or, if you're already using a third-party HTML helper, something like
// use BootstrapUI\View\Helper\HtmlHelper as HtmlHelper;

class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper
{
    function link($title, $url = null, array $options = [])
    {
        if (checkMyPermissions($url)) {
            return parent::link($title, $url, $options);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your AppController:

```
use App\View\Helper\MyHtmlHelper;
public $helpers = [
    'Html' => ['className' => 'MyHtmlHelper'],
    // ... and all your other helpers
];
```

Comment: I think this solution would lead to massive query flooding, if I am accessing  the database für every checkMyPermissions(). Is there any other way?

Comment: Well, you said you already have an `if()` in your view, so you must be reading the required data somewhere. With a little refactoring you should be able to build something generic where the information that `checkMyPermissions` needs is either in a cache or the session or Configure::read or passed in the `$options` array.